# Get a jQuery object reference

Tags: javascript, jquery

Somewhere in my code I have the following lines, which I can't change:

```
<div class="list-clickable" onclick="javascript:update_left_frame('1', $(this));">
<div class="list-clickable" onclick="javascript:update_left_frame('2', $(this));">
<div class="list-clickable" onclick="javascript:update_left_frame('3', $(this));">
// etc...
```

A few lines of code later, I need to call that same function, so that it updates the left frame. This is generated via PHP by passing a variable number as first param:

```
<script>
  // foo = ??
  update_left_frame('3', foo);
</script>
```

I need to get the reference of the block with the same number, 3 in this example. How do I set up the 'foo' var so that it takes the corresponding block reference? I though about getting:

```
$('.list-clickable').attr('onclick')
```

But I can't get it to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rethink your design. Generating JavaScript code with PHP like that is rarely the best way of accomplishing your goal.

Comment: I would also suggest replacing inline ``onclick``, with jQuery's [``on``](http://api.jquery.com/on/) handler

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
$('.list-clickable').attr('onclick');
```

If you can give the number do something like this

```
update_left_frame('3', 
  $('div').filter(function() {
    return this.attr('onclick').match(/update_left_frame\(\'3\'/); //same number as first argument
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.list-clickable').on('click', function(){
    update_left_frame(($(this).index() + 1), $(this));
});
```

Comment: Those numbers are completely random, I can't rely on their simple position.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting an id to each of the div elements...

```
<div id="list-clickable1" class="list-clickable" onclick="javascript:update_left_frame('1', $(this));">
<div id="list-clickable2" class="list-clickable" onclick="javascript:update_left_frame('2', $(this));">
<div id="list-clickable3" class="list-clickable" onclick="javascript:update_left_frame('3', $(this));">
// etc...
```

Then to get a reference to the div, use **$('.list-clickable3')** like the example below:

```
<script>
  var ctrl = $('.list-clickable3');
  aggiorna_left_frame('3', ctrl);
</script>
```

Comment: I wouldn't be able to get the correct ID when generating the code via PHP. That would be too easy :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, I found a solution that works well.
I let PHP generate this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var foo;
    $('.list-clickable').each(function() {
        var attr = $(this).attr('onclick');
        if (attr.indexOf('frame(3') !== -1) {
            foo = $(this);
        }
    });
    update_left_frame('MY_CODE', foo);
});
```